# How to handle changing of url using native javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have code.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (e) {
  // The URL changed...
  console.log(e);
});
setInterval(() => {
  history.pushState(null, "Other page", \`/${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 200)}\`)
}, 1000);
```

So, it changes the url of page every second to not same. But I do not get the event object in console. Why?

Answer (score 1):

See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event):

> Note that just calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState() won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event will be triggered by doing a browser action such as a click on the back or forward button (or calling history.back() or history.forward() in JavaScript).

Comment: Ok, but how to handle change of url by history.pushState or history.replaceState?

Comment: You're calling those functions explicitly so you know when you are changing the history. Just make whatever DOM changes you like at the same time you manipulate the history. The `popstate` event is there so you can change things *back* when the *user* hits the back button.